# Bootstrap deja de Acceder a un Input luego de Poner Runat="Server" ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Tengo un `input`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtRangoFecha" runat="server">
```

Cuando le pongo `Runat="Server"` a este objeto `jQuery`, deja de acceder y no sale nunca más el calendario, y todo el diseño de `Bootstrap` desaparece, pero si no le pongo esto, no puedo usar el control del lado del servidor *"ASP.NET"* en *C#*.

¿Qué puedo hacer? Necesito el calendario gráfico, probé con el de *"ASP.NET"* pero el diseño no es muy bueno como el del *Bootstrap*.

Comment: Sin duda como mensiona david_rprada, yo pondria el id en la class `class="form-control pull-right txtRangoFecha"` y luego lo puedes acceder `$('.txtRangoFecha')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu javascript cambia a esto:

```
$('#<%=txtRangoFecha.ClientID%>')
```

Sucede que los ID en webforms cambian de acuerdo a dónde se encuentren (haciendo referencia a los Master Page y a sus secciones)

Comment: Otra forma es $("input[id~='txtRangoFecha']"), este selecctor busca en este caso por la propiedad ID y luego entrega los elementos que contengan un id similar a txtRangoFecha, ya que webform te cambia el id a algo como mastepage_txtRangoFecha_algomasquenorecuerdo... pero definitivamente recomiendo la que te indica @fredyfx o apuntar tu selector a otro atributo de tu elemento (role u otro que puedas usar)

Answer (score 1):

La opción de utilizar `$('#<%=txtRangoFecha.ClientID%>')` tiene la desventaja que sólo podrás utilizarlo desde archivos .aspx, pero no podrás hacerlo por ejemplo desde archivos .js

En mi opinión es mucho más limpio acceder al elemento a través de selectores .css o bien añadir atributos propios al elemento html que te permitan acceder al control. Fijate en el atributo propio añadido `clientId` (podría ser cualquiera):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtRangoFecha" clientId = "txtRangoFecha" runat="server">
```

Después con jquery podrás seleccionar el input a través del atributo propio.

```
$("input[clientId='txtRangoFecha']")
```

Aquí tienes una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227170/accessing-asp-net-controls-using-jquery-all-options) completa con todas las opciones disponibles.