# Tomar tag de la pagina maestra desde otro .aspx

Tags: asp.net

Cómo lo hago para poder tomar un tag de la pagina maestra y ponerlo en oculto mediante un .hide() , cuando un usuario se haya logeado? Para el verificar el logeo utilizo c# , algo de este estilo:

```
if (usuario.nombre==Login.text){

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script>$('#id_login').hide;</script>");
```

Pero esto no me funciona ya que el #id_login está en la pagina maestra y no me lo coge desde aquí .
Lo que quiero hacer es ocultar donde dice Iniciar sesión una vez ya se haya iniciado la sesión correctamente . Y ese tag , esta en la página maestra que contiene el "header" común de todos los .aspx del proyecto

Comment: Posible duplicada a http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33262/bootstrap-deja-de-acceder-a-un-input-luego-de-poner-runat-server-asp-net-c/34450#34450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas master page los id asignados a los controles son renombrados por asp.net, es por eso que usar directo el id no funciona

Si la idea es usar jquery podrias seelccionar por aproximacion usando

```
string script = "$(\"[id*='id_login']\").hide();";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", script, true);
```

en jquery el `*=` es un selecotr de `like` en este caso usa el id

Si inspeccionas el html usando el Developr Tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, podras ver que id signa asp.net a este control que quieres seleccionar